Aggregate a list of Python dictionaries with repeated elements and add a new key with the number of repeated elements
I would like to consolidate, aggregate the following list of dictionaries based on repeated elements and include a new key indicated the number of repetitions for this particular dictionary.
Initial dictionary:
list_ = [
    {'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50')}, 
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')}, 
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')}, 
    {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00')}]

As you can see, there are 2 entries with 'id': 1, so the result I would like to have is:
list_ = [
    {'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50'), 'QUANTITY': 1}, 
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50'), 'QUANTITY': 2}, 
    {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00'), 'QUANTITY': 1}]

I have tried collections, but that aggregates all elements:
result = Counter()
for prod in list_:
    result.update(prod)
    print(result)

Counter({'id': 7, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidadesTonic Water 300 mlTonic Water 300 mlHofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': '8.004.504.506.50'})

Can anyone give me some hints here, please?

You may need to check to see if they are identical. If you can rely on id alone, the list should be a dict.

How do you determine precedence when (if) for any given id the prodDescription and/or prodPrice differ?

You're close with the Counter, you just need to count by ID.
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(d['id'] for d in list_)

Then to convert that into the output you want, deduplicate the dicts by ID and add the quantity key.
by_id = {d['id']: d for d in list_}  # Saves last occurrence
result = [{**by_id[k], 'QUANTITY': v} for k, v in counts.items()]

Result:
[{'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50'), 'QUANTITY': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50'), 'QUANTITY': 2},
 {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00'), 'QUANTITY': 1}]


You can achieve this by iterating through the list of dictionaries, keeping track of the counts of each item using a dictionary, and then adding a new key 'QUANTITY' to each dictionary with the corresponding count.
from collections import defaultdict
from decimal import Decimal

list_ = [
    {'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 
     'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50')},
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 
     'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')},
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 
     'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')},
    {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 
     'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00')}
]

# Dictionary to keep track of counts of each item
item_counts = defaultdict(int)

# Count occurrences of each item
for item in list_:
    item_counts[item['id']] += 1

# Add 'QUANTITY' key to each dictionary in the list
for item in list_:
    item['QUANTITY'] = item_counts[item['id']]

print(list_)


I dont think there is any specific library that does what you want. But you can write a simple code to perform the same.
encountered_ids = {}

# List to store the output dictionaries
output_list = []

for item in list_:
    id_val = item['id']
    if id_val not in encountered_ids:
        encountered_ids[id_val] = 1
        output_list.append(item)
    else:
        encountered_ids[id_val] += 1

# Update QUANTITY for repeated ids
for item in output_list:
    item['QUANTITY'] = encountered_ids[item['id']]

print(output_list)


Pandas can do what they want :) There's a bit of overhead though.

You can use Pandas to make this a lot easier.
First, load your data into a DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
print(df)

   id            prodDescription prodPrice
0   2  Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml      6.50
1   1         Tonic Water 300 ml      4.50
2   1         Tonic Water 300 ml      4.50
3   3         Coxinha 6 unidades      8.00

Then to do what you want:

Group rows by ID
Get size of each group and call it QUANTITY
Get first row of each group and join with QUANTITY

g = df.groupby('id')
result = g.first().join(
    g.size().rename('QUANTITY')
)
print(result)

              prodDescription prodPrice  QUANTITY
id
1          Tonic Water 300 ml      4.50         2
2   Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml      6.50         1
3          Coxinha 6 unidades      8.00         1

At this point, id is the index (like the keys of a dictionary), but it can be reset with .reset_index(). To get a list of dicts out, you can use result.reset_index().to_dict('records'), though if you have more work to do on this data, you might want to leave it as a DataFrame while you do. For example, you can easily get the sum of the quantities like so: result['QUANTITY'].sum() → 4.

Using itertools.groupby (being sure to sort on the key first):
from decimal import Decimal
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list_ = [
    {'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50')}, 
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')}, 
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')}, 
    {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00')}
]

get_id = itemgetter('id')

g = groupby(sorted(list_, key=get_id), key=get_id)

result = [
    {**v[0], 'QUANTITY': len(v)} 
    for _, v_ in g for 
    v in [list(v_)]
]

And now result is:
[
    {'id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50'), 'QUANTITY': 2}, 
    {'id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50'), 'QUANTITY': 1}, 
    {'id': 3, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00'), 'QUANTITY': 1}
]

